# Proper way to include code in PHP website

Tags: php, html

I am developing a website, 150 files, lot of code there; at least for me, a begginer.

There are many places where I repeat PHP echoes that outputs HTML, each of them with a lot of PHP variables. I am thinking about the best way not to repeat this parts.

Given this HTML:

```
    <main>
        <section>
            <?php
            $query = "SELECT a, b, c, d, e FROM table1";
            $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $table1_a = $row['a'];
                $table1_b = $row['b'];
                $table1_c = $row['c'];
                $table1_d = $row['d'];
                $table1_e = $row['e'];
                echo 'This code is thirty lines long and appears 
                identical in many places in the website. 
                It uses many variables, like '.$table1_a.','.$table1_b.',
                '.$table1_c.','.$table1_d.','.$table1_e.', and others';
            }
            ?>
        </section>
        <section>
            <?php
            $query = "SELECT a, b, c, d, e FROM table2";
            $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $table2_a = $row['a'];
                $table2_b = $row['b'];
                $table2_c = $row['c'];
                $table2_d = $row['d'];
                $table2_e = $row['e'];
                echo 'This second code is different to the other, 
                but is thirty lines long as well and is repeated
                in many other places of the website. 
                It uses many variables, like'.$table2_a.',
                '.$table2_b.','.$table2_c.','.$table2_d.',
                '.$table2_e.' and others';
            }
            ?>
        </section>
    </main>
```

I imagine two ways: with includes and with functions

With the includes I would write the echoes —without the querys, because they are all different— in separated files inside the folder /includes, and then I call them in the page.

A file in includes/echo_1.php for the includes would be like:

```
<?php
    echo 'This second code is different to the other, 
    but is thirty lines long as well and appears identical in 
    many other places of the website. 
    It uses many variables, like '.$table2_a.','.$table2_b.','.$table2_c.',
    '.$table2_d.','.$table2_e.' and others';
?>
```

And a function in functions/echo_1.php would be:

```
<?php
    function echo_1($table1_a,$table1_b,$table1_c,$table1_d,$table1_e){
        echo 'This second code is different to the other, but is thirty lines
        long as well and appears identical in many other places of the website.                    
        It uses many variables, like 
        '.$table1_a.','.$table1_b.','.$table1_c.','.$table1_d.',
        '.$table1_e.' and others';
    }
?>
```

And the calls:

```
    <main>
        <section>
            <?php
            $query = "SELECT a, b, c, d, e FROM table1";
            $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $table1_a = $row['a'];
                $table1_b = $row['b'];
                $table1_c = $row['c'];
                $table1_d = $row['d'];
                $table1_e = $row['e'];
                //Calling the include from the file echo_1.php
                include 'includes/echo_1.php';
            }
            ?>
        </section>
        <section>
            <?php
            $query = "SELECT a, b, c, d, e FROM table2";
            $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $table2_a = $row['a'];
                $table2_b = $row['b'];
                $table2_c = $row['c'];
                $table2_d = $row['d'];
                $table2_e = $row['e'];
                //Using the function echo_1 to create the echo
                echo_1($table1_a,$table1_b,$table1_c,$table1_d,$table1_e);

            }
            ?>
        </section>
    </main>
```

Also, there is the possibility that the echoes has parts of code —with querys— that are repeated between other different echoes, and I think it would be great not to repeat them, maybe with another includes or another functions inside them.

With includes I am going to make a lot of calls to another files, and that could slow the website. With functions I am going to make only one call, but I don't know if this would work better. Which option is the most efficient way to proceed, with includes or with functions? Any advise about writing maintainable code will be welcome!

N.

Comment: I suggest you look into an mvc framework

Comment: Yeah, Robert is right. Start with something like Laravel that is already opinionated with some best practices on this.

Comment: It's better to use a framework , otherwise you must follow mvc architecture  you can also use a templating engine like twig

Comment: Thank you, I will check the frameworks!

Answer (score 1):

There are better ways to do this but to prevent repeating yourself somewhat you could make this change:

```
<main>
    <section>
        <?php
        section('table1');
        ?>
    </section>
    <section>
        <?php
        section('table2');
        ?>
    </section>
</main>
```

And your function:

```
function section( $table ) {
            $query = "SELECT a, b, c, d, e FROM $table";
            $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $table_a = $row['a'];
                $table_b = $row['b'];
                $table_c = $row['c'];
                $table_d = $row['d'];
                $table_e = $row['e'];
                echo 'This code is thirty lines long and appears 
                identical in many places in the website. 
                It uses many variables, like '.$table_a.','.$table_b.',
                '.$table_c.','.$table_d.','.$table_e.', and others';
            }
}
```

Comment: So it is common to use functions for including code… And with Querys inside! That's good…
The problem is that the Querys are all different, so is not useful to put them inside the functions, because then I will need as many functions as pieces of repeated code, and I will not reduce it.

Comment: That is not too obvious from your example code. It can still work, you just need to send more information than just the tablename. Use of arrays may be helpful in this case.